# What code is responsible for adding two matrices in Numpy?

Tags: c, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm writing a program in C that adds two matrices (I'm also using BLAS). I want to see how this is done in numpy, to make sure I do matrix addition efficiently:

https://github.com/numpy/numpy

Can anyone help me find the C source code in numpy Github repository that does matrix addition?

Comment: Partial answer here... in `number.c`, `array_add` dispatches to a dtype-specific ufunc registered via `PyArray_SetNumericOps`, but unfortunately I had trouble finding what invokes it (and thus where the actual implementation lies. There is a discussion about refactoring it: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/8d1239363a6eef9bf2000ad75f24bb93e45f33bf/doc/neps/nep-0015-merge-multiarray-umath.rst.  I'm on mobile so I can't check, but it looks like the actual code is generated from either loops.c.src or scalarmath.c.src in the umath/ directory.

Comment: You can't isolate addition from the whole its array handling.  The data vuffer, dtype, strides, broadcasting all play a role.  Add is just one of  many binary ufunc.